# How to serialize some Array/Class as Attribute to XML C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to find a way how to serialize some array or class/struct as Attribute of element not like inner element/elements.

I want to make in such way:

```
<SomeElement Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Not like:

```
<Margin>
   <Left/>
   <Top/>
   <Right/>
   <Bottom/>
</Margin>
```

Comment: ...are you trying to generate UWP/WPF XAML using `XmlSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately XMLSerializer doesnt provide a solution to your problem. However, you can add your own implementation to get the desired output.

```
public class SomeElement
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Margin")]
    public string MarginString { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<int> MarginList
    {
        get
        {
            return MarginString.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Trim())).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            MarginString = String.Join(",", value);
        }
    }
}


var somelement = new SomeElement { MarginList = new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(somelement.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, somelement);
```